# Await causing main thread to hold?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

Please see the code below, which I have adapted from the following webpage: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/introduction-to-async-and-await-keywords-in-c-5.0.htm

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim program As New Program()
        Await program.PrintSumAsync()
        MsgBox("got here 1")
    End Sub
End Class

Class Program

    Public Async Function PrintSumAsync() As Task
        Dim value1 As Integer = Await GetValueAsync()
        Dim value2 As Integer = Await GetValueAsync()

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of two random numbers is: {0}", value1 + value2)
    End Function

    Private Async Function GetValueAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Dim random As Integer = ComputeValue()
        Return random
    End Function


    Private Function ComputeValue() As Integer
        MsgBox("got here 2")
        Return New Random().[Next](1, 1000)

    End Function
End Class
```

I have added a call to Sleep in the GetValueAsync so that it takes a while to finish.

I expected the code to reach msgbox1 (got here 1) before msgbox2 (got here 2).  Await seems to stop the main thread.  What am I missing? I don't have any experience with the newish await keyword.  I upgraded from .net 3.5 to .NET 4.5.2 recently.

**Update**
Based on Davids answer I have edited the code as follows:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        test()
        MsgBox("got here 1")
    End Sub

    Public Async Sub test()
        Dim program As New Program()
        Await program.PrintSumAsync()
        'Dim task As Task = program.PrintSumAsync()
        MsgBox("got here 2")
    End Sub
End Class

Class Program

    Public Async Function PrintSumAsync() As Task
        Dim value1 As Integer = Await GetValueAsync()
        Dim value2 As Integer = Await GetValueAsync()

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of two random numbers is: {0}", value1 + value2)
    End Function

    Private Async Function GetValueAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
        Try
            Await Task.Delay(5000)
            Dim random As Integer = ComputeValue()
            Return random
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Function


    Private Function ComputeValue() As Integer
        MsgBox("got here 2")
        Return New Random().[Next](1, 1000)
    End Function
End Class
```

How can I stop the main thread from finishing before message box 2 appears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Await` isn't stopping the main thread, you are:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

There's nothing *asynchronous* happening in this method:

```
Private Async Function GetValueAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Dim random As Integer = ComputeValue()
    Return random
End Function
```

(I'm surprised the compiler isn't complaining about it.  It does with C#.)  So even though the method signature and consuming code is decorated with `Async` and `Await` keywords, the resulting code isn't actually asynchronous.  It *can* be, however, if you await an asynchronous operation in that method.  For example:

```
Private Async Function GetValueAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
    Await Task.Delay(5000)
    Dim random As Integer = ComputeValue()
    Return random
End Function
```

This will make the entire stack of operations in question asynchronous, making full use of the new keywords.

Note, however, that the observed results will probably still be the same.  Take a look at the top level method:

```
Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim program As New Program()
    Await program.PrintSumAsync()
    MsgBox("got here 1")
End Sub
```

The code in that method still isn't going to execute the third line until after the second line has been awaited until completion.  The *very top level* (the UI invoking this handler) will continue without waiting on *this* method, but this method will wait until its asynchronous operations are complete before it continues.

In order to get the result you're looking for, you would want to capture the `Task` instead of awaiting it.  Something like this:

```
Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim program As New Program()
    Dim task As Task = program.PrintSumAsync()
    MsgBox("got here 1")
    ' do something with the task object.
    ' await it, provide it with a callback function for when it completes, etc.
End Sub
```

The `Async` and `Await` keywords don't necessarily make a function happen on a new thread.  For most intents and purposes, you can very often think of them as simply syntactic shorthand for wrapping part of a method in a `ContinueWith()` on a `Task` object.  In any given `Async` method, there needs to be an `Await` at which to place that `ContinueWith()`.  If there's no `Await` within it, then the `Async` method isn't asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks +1.  I have edited the question based on your answer.  Could you take a look?

Comment: @w0051977: I'm not sure what your updated question is asking.  Do the message boxes not appear in order in the updated code?  What behavior are you seeing and what are you trying to achieve?  It's not clear to me what you mean by "stop the main thread from finishing".

Comment: In the second fragment of code I do not want the main thread to finish until the two asynchronous calls have finished. Does that make sense?

Comment: @w0051977: Well, the call to `test()` isn't being awaited. The `test` method should return a `Task`, then the method invoking it can await it or in some other way manage the asynchronous task. But I'm really not clear on what you mean by "do not want the main thread to finish". How is the main thread "finishing"? I would expect the UI to invoke the asynchronous handler and then continue to handle user input while the asynchronous handler does its work. Are you trying to *block* the main thread? If so, just don't use async at all.

Comment: "finishing" means the program reaches the end of the form load before the asynchronous calls finish.

Comment: @w0051977: Ah, that depends on the application host.  This very commonly happens in a console application, for example.  And it's a demonstration of why async methods should *always* return a task and why that task should *always* be awaited *somewhere*.  Either right away, or in some post-processing operation.  A WinForms app usually doesn't demonstrate this because it's idle long enough for tasks to complete while waiting for the user to click something, but console applications finish immediately and the synchronization context doesn't block them from completing.  The code has to.

Answer (score 1):

Just for grits and shins, play with this.  It seemed to me like the process of getting the random values should be running in **parallel**:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now
        Label2.Text = ""

        Await test()

        Label2.Text = DateTime.Now
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Public Async Function test() As Task
        Dim program As New Program()
        Await Task.Run(New Action(AddressOf program.PrintSum))
    End Function

End Class

Class Program

    Private R As New Random

    Public Sub PrintSum()
        ' get some random values IN PARALLEL and wait for them all to finish
        Dim tasks As New List(Of Task(Of Integer))
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            tasks.Add(Task(Of Integer).Factory.StartNew(Function() GetValue()))
        Next
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray)
        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To tasks.Count - 1
            sum = sum + tasks(i).Result
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of the random numbers is: " & sum)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetValue() As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("Getting value...")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10001)) ' random 3 to 10 second delay
        Return ComputeValue()
    End Function

    Private Function ComputeValue() As Integer
        Dim i As Integer = R.Next(1, 1000)
        Console.WriteLine("Value selected: " & i)
        Return i
    End Function

End Class
```