# c# await (2) of them

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have 2 awaits that I run to get data from an external service:

```
aaa= await Gateway.GetMyAAA();
bbb= await Gateway.GetBBBB();
```

I want both to run at the same time and then when both are done, to continue.

How do I Wait for them all ?

Comment: See my silly example posted in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27535736/2330053) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `await` until you get the reference to all the tasks.  Then `await` them all at once.

```
Task aaa = Gateway.GetMyAAA();
Task bbb = Gateway.GetBBBB();

await Task.WhenAll(aaa, bbb);

'all tasks are complete at this time. now we get the results

var aaaResult = await aaa;
var bbbResult = await bbb;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

`results` is the array of your results and

`results[0]` is the result of your task1

Comment: Thanks. But how do I get the values out of aaa and bbb?

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com see the return parameter of WhenAll.

Comment: @PeterDuniho this simple code makes me believe `var res = await Task.WhenAll( Task.FromResult(Color.Red), Task.FromResult(Color.Blue) ); Console.WriteLine(res[0]);` Any more question?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Wrong overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -3):

First, you need to save the `Task` instances, rather than awaiting them directly:

```
Task aaaTask = Gateway.GetMyAAA(), bbbTask = Gateway.GetMyBBBB();
```

Then you wait both (all) of them in a single call to `WhenAll()`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(aaaTask, bbbTask);
```

Finally, you retrieve the results:

```
aaa = await aaaTask;
bbb = await bbbTask;
```

Note that the final `await` statements will complete synchronously. The `await` statement mainly is there so that the compiler will automatically unpack any exceptions that might have occurred and cause them to be thrown "normally", instead of in an aggregated exception.